# Post Request does no work and does not return any errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest

I am creating an e-commerce api. on the User side of things. I have functions to create, update, delete and find a user by username. These functions are called on the user controllers with appropriate requests. The problem is, when i make a post to create a user, postman returns a 200 OK response, but no record is created. Please someone help out

```
"use strict";

const findByUsername = async (username) => {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    pool.query(
      "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = $1",
      [username],
      (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
          rej(error);
        }
        res(results.rows[0]);
      }
    );
  });
};

/**
 * Request to delete user
 * This request instantly deletes a user. This action should be implemented with prior dialogs and confirmations because it is not reversibe
 *
 * no response value expected for this operation
 **/
const delete_user = (id) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    pool.query("DELETE FROM users WHERE ID = $1", [id], (error, results) => {
      if (error) {
        reject(error);
        throw error;
      }
      resolve(results.rows);
    });
  });
};

/**
 * Gets page to register user
 * Allows access to page where user can register
 *
 * no response value expected for this operation
 **/
const get_register = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve();
  });
};

/**
 * Gets page to update user details
 * Allows access to the page from where user can update details
 *
 * no response value expected for this operation
 **/
const get_update = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve();
  });
};

/**
 * Submits request to create a user
 * Submits a post request that creates a user
 *
 * no response value expected for this operation
 **/
const post_register = async (
  first_name,
  last_name,
  birth_date,
  gender,
  home_address,
  country_of_residence,
  phone,
  pword,
  username
) => {
  const checkUser = await findByUsername(username);
  if (checkUser) {
    console.log(`${username} already exists`);
    //res.redirect("/users/login");
    return;
  }

  const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);

  const password = await bcrypt.hash(pword, salt);

  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    pool.query(
      "INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, birth_date, gender, home_address, country_of_residence, phone, pword, username) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9) RETURNING *",
      [
        first_name,
        last_name,
        birth_date,
        gender,
        home_address,
        country_of_residence,
        phone,
        password,
        username,
      ],
      (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
          rej(error);
          throw error;
        }
        console.log(results.rows);
        res(results.rows);
      }
    );
  });
};

/**
 * Submit put request to update user
 * This is where the actual put request to update user details is submitted
 *
 * no response value expected for this operation
 **/
const put_update = async (
  first_name,
  last_name,
  birth_date,
  gender,
  home_address,
  country_of_residence,
  phone,
  pword,
  username
) => {
  const salt = await new Promise((res, rej) => {
    res(bcrypt.genSalt(10));
  });
  const password = await new Promise((res_1, rej_1) => {
    res_1(bcrypt.hash(pword, salt));
  });
  return await new Promise((res_2, rej_2) => {
    pool.query(
      "UPDATE users SET first_name = $1, last_name = $2, birth_date =$3, gender =$4, home_adress=$5, country_of_residence = $6, phone = $7, pword = $8, username = $9 WHERE ID = $10",
      [
        first_name,
        last_name,
        birth_date,
        gender,
        home_address,
        country_of_residence,
        phone,
        password,
        username,
      ],
      (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
          rej_2(error);
          throw error;
        }
        res_2(results.rows);
      }
    );
  });
};

module.exports = {
  post_register,
  put_update,
  get_update,
  get_register,
  delete_user,
};`
```

Below is the controller file. Not that some of the functions not shown but exported are not relevant to this question.

```
var utils = require("../utils/writer.js");
var UserProfile = require("../service/UserProfileService");


const put_update = (req, res, next) => {
  const {
    first_name,
    last_name,
    birth_date,
    gender,
    home_address,
    country_of_residence,
    phone,
    pword,
    username,
  } = req.body;
  //call the user model for updating and json the response
  UserProfile.put_update(
    first_name,
    last_name,
    birth_date,
    gender,
    home_address,
    country_of_residence,
    phone,
    pword,
    username
  )
    .then((response) => {
      utils.writeJson(res, response);
    })
    .catch((response) => {
      utils.writeJson(res, response);
    });
};

module.exports = {
  post_register,
  put_update,
  delete_user,
  get_register,
  get_update,
};
`
```

Comment: You have an `async` function that returns a `Promise`. Is that really what you want? That means it promises a promise.

Comment: How best to implement this then. Pls

Comment: Get rid of the `async` keyword, just do `return new Promise(...)`

Comment: **Pro tip**: It is worth a lot of your time to understand `async` and `Promise` objects.

Comment: i guess i will find another way to implement this without promises. i removed async and chained promises and it still doesnt work